# Python Security Question: Is python "site-packages" a safe place to store api keys for scripting purposes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security

I have a number of different scripts that are all stored in different locations and have similar API key requirements. I want to store these keys in a safe place on my computer but also have easy access to them for current scripts and future scripts that may be written. In order to get access to do this, I've noticed that it's possible to store the keys in a `.py` file and move this to the `site-packages` that come with python installation (which has been installed on a user-by-user basis and not globally). This appears to be where other modules are stored when installed with pip. I can then access my keys simply by importing them as a module when needed. If my hard drive is encrypted and users are password protected, is this a safe and secure way to store and access these keys? I wasn't sure if pip or something similar could upload, download or update the `.py` file in a manner that could be compromising.
`ex_file.py`:

```
my_key = 'api_key_information'
```

Then the `ex_file.py` is moved to `site-packages` in the python installation file path along with other libraries like NumPy, Pandas, seaborn, etc.